# Having a problem with my prompt in linux WSL, when i write more than one line commands the command starts writing behind my prompt?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So when writing a code my code overruns not onto the next line but behind my prompt or sometime it just goes somewhere else. I have a coloured prompt and i guess maybe my code for that could be the issue... its here:

```
export PS1="\e[1;36m\u\e[m\e[1;34m@\h\e[m\e[1;36m\w\$ \e[m"
```

If not, what is causing this?

Comment: update your Q to include the output of `echo "TERM=$TERM"`. Good luck.

Comment: With just this information it's very hard to guess. I don't suspect your colored prompt is the issue though. I've seen this behavior periodically on various terminals but I don't know of a reason (much less a common reason) why it happens. Can you narrow it down to a specific set of steps so someone can reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prompt line looks strange. Afaik you always have to wrap the color changes in `\[` and `\]`.

Again not sure but as I understood `\e` is only used for single colors but if you also want to change boldness you have to use e.g. `\033[1;32m`.

Also when resetting to default it should not be `\e[m` but afaik `\e[0m`.

You also should wrap it in `''` not in `""` to avoid some dynamic variable replacements there. so in total something like.

```
export PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;34m\]@\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\033[1;36m\]\w\$ \[\e[0m\]'
```

Comment: That work perfectly to fix the issue! Thank you